# Github Pages Ignoring Updates to Dependency of Jekyll App

Tags: ruby, github, jekyll, github-pages

I have a jekyll app that uses the jekyll-seo-tag.  I forked jekyll-seo-tag to make some more tweaks.  I pushed my changes up to Github and pointed my Gemfile to the forked repo.

When I run the app locally, I see the correct (i.e. new) behavior.  When I push the jekyll app to Github, I see don't the updates.

I've inspected the `Gemfile.lock` file on Github and it's pointed to my forked repo and is using the correct SHA.

I tried to get Github to rebuild the page by sending an empty commit.

`git commit -m 'rebuild site' --allow-empty`

But it had no effect.

My guess is that when GitHub builds the app, it's using a cached version, but that's just a theory.  I get no errors anywhere.

Any idea what else I can do to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Github Pages do not allow you to use custom jekyll plugins. Period.

Comment: Welp, that explains it.  Thanks.